# Убрать ненужные скобки из математического выражения

Tags: java

Нужно чтобы при таком расположении скобок:
(15 * 4) + 3, скобки удалялись => 15 * 4 + 3. Если скобки не имеют смысла, они удаляются.

Пример:
(5 + 5) + 4 => 5 + 5 + 4

Пытался сделать на Си, но мне надо написать на Java. Код не работает, не знаю почему.

```
    void main(){
    char *num = "15+(5*A)/(2+B)+C*(2-(A + B))";
    int i, j, mark, bol = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 29; i++){
        if (num[i] == "(" && bol == 0){
            printf("\n%s", num);
            mark = i - 1;
            bol = 1;
        }
        else if (num[i] == "+" && num[mark] == "+" && bol == 1){
            num[mark + 1] = "";
            bol = 2;
        }
        else if (num[i] == "*" && (num[mark] == "-" || num[mark] == "+") && bol == 1){
            num[mark + 1] = "";
            bol = 2;
        }
        else if (num[i] == ")" && bol == 2){
            num[i] = "";
            bol = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("\n%s", num);
}
```

Сам сделал на Java

```
public class TestMinimalParen {
    private static String check_brackets(String theExpressionText){
        char str[] = theExpressionText.toCharArray();
        int bool = 0, b_Brackets = 0, f_br = 0, l_br = 0, mark = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (bool == 0 && str[i] == '('){
                f_br = i;
                bool = 1;
            }
            else if (bool == 1 && str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '*'){
                mark = i;
                bool = 2;
            }
            else if (bool == 1 && str[i] == '('){
                f_br = i;
            }
            else if (bool == 2 && str[i] == ')'){
                l_br = i;
                bool = 3;
            }
            else if (bool == 3 && str[f_br] != '?' && str[l_br] != '?'){
                b_Brackets = 0;
                if (str[f_br - 1] == '+' && str[mark] == '+' && str[l_br + 1] == '+') {
                    b_Brackets = 1;
                }
                else if (str[f_br - 1] == '+' && str[mark] == '+' && (str[l_br + 1] == '/' || l_br + 1 > str.length)){
                    b_Brackets = 1;
                }
                else if ((str[f_br - 1] == '/' || f_br - 1 <= 0) && str[mark] == '+' && str[l_br + 1] == '+'){
                    b_Brackets = 1;
                }
                else if ((str[f_br - 1] == '+' || str[f_br - 1] == '-')
                        && str[mark] == '*' && (str[l_br + 1] == '+' || str[l_br + 1] == '-')){
                    b_Brackets = 1;
                }
                else if ((str[f_br - 1] == '/' || f_br - 1 <= 0)
                        && str[mark] == '*' && (str[l_br + 1] == '+' || str[l_br + 1] == '-')){
                    b_Brackets = 1;
                }
                else if ((str[f_br - 1] == '+' || str[f_br - 1] == '-')
                        && str[mark] == '*' && (str[l_br + 1] == '/' || l_br + 1 < str.length)){
                    b_Brackets = 1;
                }
                else if ((str[f_br - 1] == '/' || f_br - 1 <= 0) && (str[l_br + 1] == '/' || l_br + 1 < str.length)){
                    b_Brackets = 1;
                }
                if (b_Brackets == 1){
                    str[f_br] = '?';
                    str[l_br] = '?';
                }
                bool = 0;
            }
        }
        String fin = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            if (str[i] != '?'){
                String f = Character.toString(str[i]);
                fin = fin + f;
            }
        }
        return fin;
    }
```

Comment: Вы двигаетесь не в том направлении. Для начала вам нужно распарсить выражение в промежуточное представление и  работать уже с ним. Вот по быстрому нагуглилось для JS, но принципы везде одни и те же будут. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/parsing-math-expressions-with-javascript-7e8f5572276e (см. второй раздел, про AST)

Comment: 1. Парсим всё вырадение. 2. Записываем выражение заново.